# How can I use perl regex to remove the first directory name (top level) of a string

Tags: regex, perl

I'm making a Wakaba image board using the perl script I can download. However one thing that has perplexed me is the function "expand_filename($)" which will expand the path of the filename.

Everything, on all files, including my images, it would add /~ponydash/ to the end, ponydash is the name of my account on the hosting, so I created a debug function to see what it would return, it is as follows:

```
sub debug_string()
{
    my ($filename)=@_;
    return $filename if($filename=~m!^/!);
    return $filename if($filename=~m!^\w+:!);

    my ($self_path)=$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}=~m!^(.*/)[^/]+$!;
    return $self_path;
}
```

And when called in the HTML document with

```
<var debug_string()>
```

It would return:

```
/~ponydash/b/
```

Now I want to know how I could modify the third to last line to remove the /~ponydash/ part to just leave /b/.

Answer (score 3):

This should return only the second path part to the end of the path:

```
^\/[^\/]*(\/.*)$
```

The first / and all preceding non-slash characters are ignored up to the second slash which will be captured like the rest of the string.